# mysql joining the same table twice running very slow with wrong result

Tags: mysql, database

```
SELECT `apps`.*,
       COUNT(all_users.id) AS total_users,
       COUNT(active_users.id) AS active_users
FROM `apps`
INNER JOIN `social_users` AS `all_users` ON `all_users`.`app_id` = `apps`.`id`
INNER JOIN `social_users` AS `active_users` ON `active_users`.`app_id` = `apps`.`id`
WHERE `active_users`.`is_active` = 'true'
GROUP BY `id`
ORDER BY `total_users` ASC LIMIT 30
OFFSET 0
```

I have 2 tables.
`apps -> id, name`
`social_user -> id, app_id, is_active`

I want to run a query on apps table and show all the total users and all the active users.
I join social_users twice.
The problem is that if I join it once (no matter which) it runs very fast. the second join kill the performance and the numbers are not accurate at all, I get 180000 users instead of 750.

how can I do it better and faster?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that this is the query you are running? You say `I get 180000 users instead of 750` when your query is LIMITING the results: `LIMIT 30
OFFSET 0` How is that even possible?

Comment: limit doesn't apply on aggregate functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT `apps`.*,
       COUNT(all_users.id) AS total_users,
       SUM(IF(all_users.is_active='true',1,0)) AS active_users
  FROM `apps`
 INNER JOIN `social_users` AS `all_users` ON `all_users`.`app_id` = `apps`.`id`
 GROUP BY `id`
 ORDER BY `total_users` ASC LIMIT 30
OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score 1):

the speed is going to depend greatly on your indexes, however the first issue i see is that you need to move your `WHERE` clause into your `ON` clause for the `active_users` table:

```
SELECT `apps`.*,
       COUNT(all_users.id) AS total_users,
       COUNT(active_users.id) AS active_users
FROM `apps`
INNER JOIN `social_users` AS `all_users` ON `all_users`.`app_id` = `apps`.`id`
INNER JOIN `social_users` AS `active_users` ON `active_users`.`app_id` = `apps`.`id`
       AND `active_users`.`is_active` = 'true'
GROUP BY `id`
ORDER BY `total_users` ASC LIMIT 30
OFFSET 0
```

this should at least get you the right number of results.  to avoid linking twice, you can make your second COUNT() conditional as well, consider:

```
SELECT `apps`.*,
       COUNT(all_users.id) AS total_users,
       COUNT(IF(all_users.is_active = 'true',all_users.id,NULL)) AS active_users
FROM `apps`
INNER JOIN `social_users` AS `all_users` ON `all_users`.`app_id` = `apps`.`id`
GROUP BY `id`
ORDER BY `total_users` ASC LIMIT 30
OFFSET 0
```

this way you only link to the table once, and only count conditionally if they are active for your active count.

good luck!